# How to fix NativeScript file upload on some files aborts the upload after just 196608 bytes

Tags: ios, file, upload, nativescript, upload-max-filesize

On some files, (ios) at the moment is the only platform I'm testing on, if the file is under 30 megs everything seems to work using nativescript-background-http to upload a video file to the server.  If the filesize is over 30 megs the upload aborts at exactly 196608 bytes every time.

I know it's not a server issue aborting the upload.  As I have set both the POST Size Limits in IIS and the Max File Size Limit in ColdFusion to 500 megs.

```
mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
    let results = res.object.get('results');

    if (results) {

        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            let result = results[i];
            let file = result.file;

            if (result.file && applicationModule.ios) 
            {
                console.dir(result);

                // We can copy it to app directory, if need
                //let fileName = "myTmpImage.mov";

                var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
                var sFile = result.file.replace("file://", "");

                var filename = sFile.substring(sFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var mimetype = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                console.log(sFile);

                var request = {
                    url: 'http://www.mobilecoach.me/test_upload.cfm',
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                        "File-Name" : filename
                    },
                    description: "Uploading"
                };

                var params = [
                    { name: "file", filename: sFile, mimeType: "video/" + mimetype }
                    ];

                task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
                task.on("progress", logEvent);
                task.on("error", logEvent);
                task.on("complete", logEvent);

                function logEvent(e) {
                    console.log("currentBytes: " + e.currentBytes);
                    console.log("totalBytes: " + e.totalBytes);
                    console.log(e.eventName);

                    if(e.eventName == "complete")
                    {
                        dialogsModule.alert({
                            message: "Upload Completed",
                            okButtonText: "Ok",
                            cancelable: false
                            }).then(() => {

                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Like I said on less than 30 meg files works fine.  Over 30 megs upload aborts without error just completes/aborts @ exactly 196608 bytes.

Comment: did you try to upload it outside of nativescript to make sure it's working? (maybe with Postman)

Comment: Do you keep the screen on & app active while uploading? Do you get any error? As mentioned above, did you get a chance to verify your API with tools like Postman?

Comment: Okay so here's what I've been able to diagnose so far if I console.dir(e) inside the logEvent method here is what I get...

Comment: responseCode: 200
response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2829061a0> { URL: http://www.mobilecoach.me/test_upload.cfm } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Content-Encoding" =     (
gzip
);
"Content-Length" =     (
120
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"text/html;charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
"Wed, 02 Jan 2019 17:15:01 GMT"
);
Server =     (
"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
);
Vary =     (
"Accept-Encoding"
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
"ASP.NET"
);
} }  That is on success

Comment: responseCode: 404
response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x282928500> { URL: http://www.mobilecoach.me/test_upload.cfm } { Status Code: 404, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
private
);
Connection =     (
close
);
"Content-Length" =     (
4982
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"text/html; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
"Wed, 02 Jan 2019 17:15:43 GMT"
);
Server =     (
"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
);
"X-Powered-By" =     (
"ASP.NET"
);
} }  This is when it fails...

Comment: Manoj, yes the screen is left open but it happens so quick....like 7 progress events and then boom, complete event fires.

Comment: @BrentZiemann, you can try this plugin: https://github.com/mobilemindtec/nativescript-background-task

Comment: Okay finally diagnosed the error.  Once the file headers are sent to the server there's a setting in IIS10 that has to be changed along with post size to accept larger files.  If it's not it throws a 404 error and closes the connection immediately.

Comment: @jibon57 Thank you!  Though I fixed my original issue this will be a huge help in another part of the project I'm working on!  About how long does it take to zip files prior to upload? On average, I'm sure on really old phones, it'll take longer.

Comment: @BrentZiemann Can i know which setting you changed to fix this?